# Using Aptana Studio with Dojo toolkit in Adobe AIR?

Tags: dojo, adobe, air

I'm testing a little bit of Adobe AIR - the HTML version in Aptana. And I chose Dojo Toolkit as the JS framework to have. And the generated html-page with dojo ain't working. 
That I think is a little bit embarrasing. 
And when I deploy the application it is so big, can you strip away all the pieces of the library that you don't use? Like Dojox I don't use at all. I propably won't use more than a third of the dijix controls either.

Have anybody else any thoughts on Adobe AIR development - the HTML version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Dojo in AIR myself, but I do believe you need to do a custom build via the [Dojo build system](http://docs.dojocampus.org/build/index) for it to work. AIR does not allow the default Dojo module loader to work correctly. With the build system, you could exclude dojox from the resulting build by omitting it from the prefixes part of your build profile.

Sitepen did a dojo-based [Netflix AIR application](http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2009/02/queued_movie_manager_adobe_air.html) a while back, and apparently they put [their source code up](http://code.google.com/p/queued/). It might give some clues on the kinds of things needed to work in the AIR environment. Looks like the example-build.sh file gives a hint on how they did the custom build for the app.